# insert specific text after line 2 with batch programming

Tags: batch-file

I have a file that looks like this

0181830207709014000015576526S00000140000014000001242017
0052500056661095000015576527S00000950000095000001242017
0157020294103030000015576528S00000300000030000001242017
2397870060994031500015576529S00000315000031500001242017
2466260219154015000015576530S00000150000015000001242017

I need to insert a specific text called "insert me a new line" after line2 and redirect the output to a new file with a different file name. how can i solve this using batch programming.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Findstr /N` to number the lines of the file

```
> findstr /N ".*" test.txt
1:0181830207709014000015576526S00000140000014000001242017
2:0052500056661095000015576527S00000950000095000001242017
3:0157020294103030000015576528S00000300000030000001242017
4:2397870060994031500015576529S00000315000031500001242017
5:2466260219154015000015576530S00000150000015000001242017
```

And a `For /f` loop to parse the output, splitting at the colon into vars `%%A`  for the number and `%%B` for the line content. If the number is `2` insert the extra line.

```
@Echo off
Set "File=Test.txt"
Set "NewFile=TestNew.txt"
(
  For /f "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A in (
    'Findstr /N ".*" "%File%"'
  ) Do If %%A Equ 2 (
    Echo:insert me a new line before
    Echo:%%B
    Echo:insert me a new line below
  ) Else (
    Echo:%%B
  )
) >"%NewFile%"
```

**EDIT** changed the logic for followup readers. Sample Output:

```
> type TestNew.txt
0181830207709014000015576526S00000140000014000001242017
insert me a new line before
0052500056661095000015576527S00000950000095000001242017
insert me a new line below
0157020294103030000015576528S00000300000030000001242017
2397870060994031500015576529S00000315000031500001242017
2466260219154015000015576530S00000150000015000001242017
```

Comment: ok. that worked. i did not even know about the findstr /N expression. thank you

Comment: @neewbee You might consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)