# Insert a command into a specific line from batch file to another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to insert the following command to the 1st line
& a self destruct command to the last line
of another batch

```
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
```

my batch:

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
CD %~dp0mkvtoolnix
pause. >nul | echo. Press Enter To Analyze MKV Files
echo.  Analyzing MKV Files
@echo on
%~dp0ChapterUnorderer.exe %~dp0 [-o] [-f]

<New command that  I require>

@echo off
pause. >nul | echo.  Press Enter To Remux
START %~dp0ChapterUnorderer.bat

pause
del "%~dp0ChapterUnorderer.bat"
```

EDIT this batch cant have absolute paths & my batch has spaces in the name if that helps

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to insert a self destruct command and the one menttioned using this batch to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your prepend:

```
Echo New first line>Newfile
more oldfile>>newfile
ren oldfile oldfile.bak
ren newfile oldfile
```

If you want to replace the first line in oldfile insert `+1` following more.

For the self destruct see [this answer from @dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333575/6811411)

Comment: more like insert a command by creating and shifting the rest of the commands one line below in the batch

Comment: This is the simplest approach for the first line, there is no sed delivered with windows. But to give you [a more versatile answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006613/insert-specific-text-after-line-2-with-batch-programming)

Comment: wow thats exactly what I need but it inserts to the first line, I need the top most line to be inserted

Comment: You choose the line number by editing `If %%A Neq 2`

Comment: already tried it inserted the line below first when I wrote Neq 1

Comment: Well the batch is written to insert below the numbered  line, if you  want to change to insert before reverse the following two echo lines.

Comment: @Mav Changed the referenced batch to be more descriptive, would be nice to get a vote up on either or an accepted answer here.